# How to use the function 'predict' of svm_model in libsvm?

Tags: python, api, svm, libsvm

In recent version of libsvm(v3.17 2013.04.01), the method 'predict' in class 'svm_model' has been removed.

The alternative method seems to be method 'svm_predict' in module 'svmutil'. But I can't understand the parameter data(y,x) of this method.

`def svm_predict(y, x, m, options=""):`

```
"""
svm_predict(y, x, m [, options]) -> (p_labels, p_acc, p_vals)

Predict data (y, x) with the SVM model m. 
options: 
    -b probability_estimates: whether to predict probability estimates, 
        0 or 1 (default 0); for one-class SVM only 0 is supported.
    -q : quiet mode (no outputs).

The return tuple contains
p_labels: a list of predicted labels
p_acc: a tuple including  accuracy (for classification), mean-squared 
       error, and squared correlation coefficient (for regression).
p_vals: a list of decision values or probability estimates (if '-b 1' 
        is specified). If k is the number of classes, for decision values,
        each element includes results of predicting k(k-1)/2 binary-class
        SVMs. For probabilities, each element contains k values indicating
        the probability that the testing instance is in each class.
        Note that the order of classes here is the same as 'model.label'
        field in the model structure.
"""
```

Answer (score 5):

"y" are the labels and correspond with the datapoint in "x"

Here is an example of something I did last month:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from svmutil import *

model = svm_load_model("train_yesterday.model")

values=[{1:1.37599, 2:1.37597, 3:1.37597, 4:1.37587, 5:1.37586}]
newcurve = []

for j in range(1,121):
    a,b,val = svm_predict([1],values,model)
    newval = val[0][0]

    for i in range(1,5):
        values[0][i] = values[0][i+1]
    values[0][5] = newval
```

Comment: If we want to predict the classification for points in "X", why would we input the corresponding "y"? Isn't that what we are trying to find?

Comment: @mxdg  It is optional in case you want to get the precision of the model, otherwise you can ignore them.